# PHP Rewrite multiple parameters at once with /param1/param2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, rewriting

I'd like to know how to rewrite multiple paramaters into /param1/param2

Let's assume I have included a file called account.php with

http://myurl.com/index.php?p=account.

It works just fine and is rewritten to

http://myurl.com/account

but let's say I want to have multiple parameters in account.php like

**http://myurl.com/index.php?p=account&settings**

which should rewritten look like:

**http://myurl.com/account/settings** How would I do that ?

.htacces file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

PHP Code to include the files:

```
 $pages = array('products','about','impressum','home','support','solutions','mc','team','account');

 $p = 'home';
 if(isset($_GET['p'])) {
 $p = $_GET['p'];
 }
 if(in_array($p, $pages)){
 include 'includes/'.$p.'.php';
 }
 else {
  include 'includes/home.php';
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work with this code in my website is does what you looking for

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^post/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ single.php?post_type=$1&post_id=$2 [QSA]
```

Comment: Could you explain what is meant by ^post/ ? I'm new to these rewrite things

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.php\?p=$1&action=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.php\?p=$1
```

for each `([a-zA-Z]+)` it adds another number to the "results"..  $1, $2, $3, etc.  So you can add as many rewrites as you want... for example, this is one of my mod rewrites...

```
#WMS LIVE EDITOR
RewriteRule ^WMS/templateeditor/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ WMS/templateeditor.php\?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3&p4=$4
RewriteRule ^WMS/templateeditor/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ WMS/templateeditor.php\?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3
RewriteRule ^WMS/templateeditor/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ WMS/templateeditor.php\?p1=$1&p2=$2
RewriteRule ^WMS/templateeditor/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ WMS/templateeditor.php\?p1=$1
RewriteRule ^WMS/templateeditor/?$ WMS/templateeditor.php
```

on the php page, just add `$_GET['action'];`

and then set up your php to where if an action is set for the page, go to that action (in this case, settings).

I just used "action" as an example...it can be whatever you want it to be.

### EDIT

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.php\?p=$1&$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.php\?p=$1
```

my php code to test results

```
$p = 'home';

if(isset($_GET['p'])) {
 $p = $_GET['p'];
     echo 'p:'. $p;
 }

echo ' ';

if(isset($_GET['settings'])) {
 echo 'yes';
 }
```

I went to `domain.com/profile/settings` and it echoed the following: `p:profile  yes`

fixing includes

```
if(file_exists('rootDir.php')) { include_once ('rootDir.php'); }
if(file_exists('../rootDir.php')) { include_once ('../rootDir.php'); }
if(file_exists('../../rootDir.php')) { include_once ('../../rootDir.php'); }
if(file_exists('../../../rootDir.php')) { include_once ('../../../rootDir.php'); }
if(file_exists('../../../../rootDir.php')) { include_once ('../../../../rootDir.php'); }
if(file_exists('../../../../../rootDir.php')) { include_once ('../../../../../rootDir.php'); }
if(file_exists('../../../../../../rootDir.php')) { include_once ('../../../../../../rootDir.php'); }
```

This will help ignore the "fake folders" in the url

```
// ---------------------------------------- http() ---- determine if http/https
if (!function_exists('http')) {
    function http() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == 'on') {$pageURL .= 's';}
 $pageURL .= '://';
 return $pageURL;
}
}
```

this is a php function that will identify whether your website is using http:// or https:// for the absolute paths

---

this is the function to get your website url for absolute paths

```
// ---------------------------------------- parse URL ---- split URL into parts
$websiteurl = http() . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
$website = parse_url($websiteurl);
$websitedomain = $website['host'];
if (strpos($websiteurl, '~') !== FALSE) {
    $subweb = explode('/', $websitedomain . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]);
    $websitedomain = $subweb[0] .'/'. $subweb[1];
}
```

---

example of how to add the code to your site

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo http() . $websitedomain .'/WMS/css/style.css'; ?>"/>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but for some reason this doesn't work. If I add your code, it doesn't even include the file anymore

Comment: I just modified..forgot to add something...try that and let me know if it works or not

Comment: Still doesn't work. All I want is to replace index.php?p=account&settings with /account/settings

Comment: look at edit.  I even set this entire scenario up on one of my sites.  It works.

Comment: note that the `$_GET['settings']` the way you are setting it up is not returning ANY results.  All it does it sets the variable settings.  You don't have `&settings=xxxxxxxx`  you only have `&settings`

Comment: Well, it works now, but for some reason the stylesheet is missing if I open account/settings. It works if I open /account but /account/settings doesn't include the stylesheet. Could you check my added php code

Comment: That is the hard part about adding htaccess rules like this to the root directory.  It throws off existing files.  You need to add absolute paths to your images/files that are not included in php includes, and you need to have a root directory added to your php for includes.

Comment: Maybe its because I'm using folder paths for them

Comment: Isn't a big deal. Thanks for your help and sorry for bugging you with mys stuff. Have a nice day

Comment: I added php code that will help you avoid having to add an actual url...that way if the domain ever changes or the http(s) status ever changes, it will automatically update

Comment: Btw: what I forgot to ask : How can I determine if no second parameter is set ?

Comment: `count($_GET)`    so... something like `if (count($_GET) == 1) { // code }`

Comment: Oh nice. Thanks. One last question: How would I need to change my include logic in the /account/ to get it working with second parameter, so /account/settings would include settings.php. Of course I can do it manually by using if(isset($_GET['settings'])){include settings.php', but there should be a much shorter way to do that for multiple files

Comment: I would stick to isset's.  There may be a shorter way but it just depends on how you are setting up your code and design.  That would be too much to go through.  You can ask another question on here as a separate post if you need help with that.  But you'll have to update your code with your updated code and you'll need to include more code probably.